# For Loop Error - Subscript Out of Bounds

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, subscript

I have been searching the internet for hours trying to resolve the following error:

```
Error in Dataset[i, Year] : subscript out of bounds
```

Below is the section of my code producing the error:

```
for(i in (2*YF):1){
    if(Dataset[i,Year] < 0){
        Dataset[i,Total_Births] <- Dataset[i,Male_Births] + Dataset[i,Female_Births]
    }else{
        Dataset[i,Total_Births] <- with(Dataset, sum(Dataset[Female_Births > (i-AEB) & Female_Births <= (i-ABB),Female_Births]))
        Dataset[i,Male_Births] <- MBR * Dataset[i,Total_Births]
        Dataset[i,Female_Births] <- FBR * Dataset[i,Total_Births]
    }
}
```

'Year' starts with 500 and ends with -500 skipping 0.

I need to populate the columns from the bottom up.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is the full code:

```
#DECLARE PARAMETERS
YF  <- 500     #Years Ago Flood Occurred
FBR  <- .5       #Historical Female Birth Rate
MBR  <- (1-FBR)  #Historical Male Birth Rate
ABF <- 12       #Average Births per Female
AL  <- 60       #Average Lifespan 
NF  <- 4        #Number of Females at Debark
NM  <- 4        #Number of Males at Debark
NAD <- 40       #Noah's Age at Debark
NWA <- 40       #Emzara's (Noah's Wife) Age at Debark
SA  <- 35       #Shem's (Noah's Son) Age at Debark
SWA <- 35       #Sedeqetelebab's (Shem's Wife) Age at Debark
HA  <- 30       #Ham (Noah's Son) Age at Debark
HWA <- 30       #Ne'elatama'uk's (Ham's Wife) Age at Debark
JA  <- 25       #Japheth (Noah's Son) Age at Debark
JWA <- 25       #Adataneses's (Japheth's Wife) Age at Debark
CP  <- 20       #Current Population of World Today
ABB <- 18       #Age Begin Births
AEB <- 30       #Age End Births


###CREATE MATRIX - YEAR###
YearA <- YF:1
YearB <- -1:-YF

Year <- c(YearA,YearB)

###POPULATE BIRTHS DATA###
BF_Male_Births <- rep.int(0,YF)
BF_Female_Births <- rep.int(0,YF)

BF_Male_Births[NAD] <- 1
BF_Female_Births[NWA] <- 1
BF_Male_Births[SA] <- 1
BF_Female_Births[SWA] <- 1
BF_Male_Births[HA] <- 1
BF_Female_Births[HWA] <- 1
BF_Male_Births[JA] <- 1
BF_Female_Births[JWA] <- 1

BF_Total_Births <- rep.int(0,YF)

AF_Male_Births <- rep.int(0,YF)
AF_Female_Births <- rep.int(0,YF)
AF_Total_Births <- c(rep.int(4,9),rep.int(3,3),rep.int(0,(YF-12))) #make parameters for 9,3,12

Male_Births <- c(AF_Male_Births,BF_Male_Births)
Female_Births <- c(AF_Female_Births,BF_Female_Births)
Total_Births <- c(AF_Total_Births,BF_Total_Births)

Total_Births <- rep.int(0,YF)

Births <- cbind(Male_Births,Female_Births,Total_Births)
Dataset <- cbind(Year,Births)

for(i in (2*YF):1){
  if(Dataset[i,Year] < 0){
    Dataset[i,Total_Births] <- Dataset[i,Male_Births] + Dataset[i,Female_Births]
  }else{
    Dataset[i,Total_Births] <- with(Dataset, sum(Dataset[Female_Births > (i-AEB) & Female_Births <= (i-ABB),Female_Births]))
    Dataset[i,Male_Births] <- MBR * Dataset[i,Total_Births]
    Dataset[i,Female_Births] <- FBR * Dataset[i,Total_Births]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at `Dataset`? It's 4x1 matrix filled with 1000. It only has 4 rows and you're trying to index from 1000 to 1. Plus did you define "Total_Births","Male_Births","Female_Births" somewhere else? It code is missing other variables as well so it is not runnable.

Comment: 1)It's a 1000x2 matrix 2)"Year","Total_Births","Male_Births","Female_Births" are Column Names 3)I didn't intend it to be runnable - I can make it runnable if you want

Comment: Well, in the code you pasted above `dim(Dataset)` is 4x1. So clearly it is not what you expected.

Comment: It was most definately 1000x4 - Regardless I added the full code and removed the two lines that were causing confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `Dataset[i,Year]`, both `i` and `Year` are treated as indicies. Since year is numeric, the subsetting operator assumes that you want those column values returned. However, `Year` is a vector with the values 500:-500 and you only have 4 columns, which is why you get the out of bounds error. It's a bit confusing because you have a `Year` vector defined outside your matrix, and a `Year` column inside your matrix.

If you do indexing with a character vector, it will match on row names and column names. So think you meant

```
Dataset[i,"Year"]
```

Same goes for all the other places where you index `Dataset`. Right now, without the quotes, Its using the values you defined outside the matrix which is not what you want.

In addition, you cannot use `with()` with a matrix. `with()` should be used with data.frames or environments or lists, and `Dataset` isn't any of those. This is closer to proper syntax

```
for(i in (2*YF):1){
  if(Dataset[i,"Year"] < 0){
    Dataset[i,"Total_Births"] <- Dataset[i,"Male_Births"] + Dataset[i,"Female_Births"]
  }else{
    Dataset[i,"Total_Births"] <- sum(Dataset[Dataset[, "Female_Births"] > (i-AEB) & Dataset[,"Female_Births"] <= (i-ABB),"Female_Births"])
    Dataset[i,"Male_Births"] <- MBR * Dataset[i,"Total_Births"]
    Dataset[i,"Female_Births"] <- FBR * Dataset[i,"Total_Births"]
  }
}
```

but it seems like you may still have some logic errors in there.

Comment: Now I am getting the following error: `Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one`